# How do I calculate the percentage of progress using raster data using Python?

Tags: python, gdal, pyqgis

How do I calculate the progress amount of two or more raster data being processed? I have seen examples of vector data but it becomes difficult to calculate the progress when no vector data are involved. I have only seen solutions for vector data here it easy by looping around the features in a vector file

Comment: Unlike when working with vectors, you can ***always*** know how many pixels will be processed, since row, column, and band counts are easily available. Even wheh partial processing in involved, it's still trival to determine the pixel count by envelope overlap.

Comment: There seems to be some ready made progress functions in GDAL http://gdal.org/java/org/gdal/gdal/TermProgressCallback.html, https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/rfc51_rasterio_resampling_progress.